# Error while dumping ethernet network card BIOS's ROM - RTL8111/8168b

Tags: 12.04, hardware, realtek, firmware

Using this tutorial ["Using the PCI sysfs interface to dump the Video BIOS ROM"](http://smackerelofopinion.blogspot.com/2011/07/using-pci-sysfs-interface-to-dump-video.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ASmackerelOfOpinion+%28A+Smackerel+of+Opinion%29) I tried to repeat the steps for dumping BIOS ROM from the network card.

My network card is:

```
$ lspci
[snip]
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 01)
```

So I typed this to be sure where my network card rom is:

```
$ find /sys/devices -name "rom"
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/rom
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:03:00.0/rom
```

It's the second result. Now I have to dump it.

So typing what has to be typed, I'm getting error:

```
$ echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:03:00.0/rom
1
$ sudo cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:03:00.0/rom > netbios.rom
cat: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:03:00.0/rom: Input/output error
```

See? Input/output error..
Using ethtool I also get an error:

```
$ sudo ethtool -e eth0 > romdump.rom
Cannot get EEPROM data: Operation not supported
```

Here's more info:

```
$ ethtool -i eth0
driver: r8169
version: 2.3LK-NAPI
firmware-version: 
bus-info: 0000:03:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
```

So it looks like my network card doesn't allow me to make dumps of its BIOS ROM, using eeprom access? But to me it's a bit confusing - I mean, it should be possible to dump any hardware's firmware, right?

Comment: Is there a message in dmesg after
`sudo cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:03:00.0/rom` ? On my box, I got :
`r8169 0000:02:00.0: Invalid ROM contents` but it's normal because I screw up my rom with a wrong flash. As side effect my MAC address has changed and I try to revert my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The sysfs `rom` file allows you to read the PCI ROM contents, but apparently the device does not expose that information. It is not available or not implemented by the device.

About why `ethtool -e eth0` fails, the current r8169 driver (up to and including 3.19-rc3) does not implement a method to read from the EEPROM. If your Realtek network device has an Atmel 93C46 or 93C56 EEPROM, then you can add this r8169 functionality with [this patch (for Linux 3.11)](https://git.lekensteyn.nl/peter/linux/commit/?h=rtl-eeprom&id=194c62ac6f1c2321d1938b60295e0cbb11661258) ([same patch, rebased for 3.17, works for 3.19 too](https://git.lekensteyn.nl/peter/linux/commit/?h=rtl-eeprom-3.17&id=55754e5441d1bb32d30d4174a524eaf2c1c18148)).

For those whose device is "bricked" (symptoms: garbage MAC address such as bb:6f:ff:ff:ff:ff, vendor/device ID reported as 10ec:8129), you could try to follow the instructions in that message. I have tried it in the past and from time to time I have to repeat it when the power is fully removed from the machine. Unfortunately, the instructions are not 100% reliable and every time I have to try much more tricks in order to get it to work. As of this writing, this RTL8169sb/8110sb is still defunct since yesterday.